# using an average function in Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, function, qualtrics

I'm trying to write a function to compute an average of embedded data. I piped the fields in, parse them (they are numbers with decimals, so I can use parseInt). Then I need to check if any of the values are zero, so I filter it. I then want to average the data points that are left over.

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{

var a = "${e://Fields/a}"
var b = "${e://Fields/b}"
var c = "${e://Fields/c}"

var a= parseFloat(a)
var b= parseFloat(b)
var c= parseFloat(c)

var  all_values;
var all_values= [a, b, c];

function isnonzero(value) {
    return value != 0;
}   

var filter_it;
var filter_it = all_values.filter(isnonzero);

function avg(filter_it){
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < filter_it.length; i++) {
sum += parseFloat(arr[i])
}
return average= sum / i;
}

Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("total",average);
```

I don't think my function is right, or the way I tried to get the info out of the function. Any help would be awesome!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Anyone helping you will need more info, including what is not right. Is there an error? Please edit the question with additional info, don't add it as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems here, first, you don't need to re-initialize a variable after it has been defined. Second, you never call your avg() function. And third, you can't use the value of i outside of the for loop. YOu also never define arr in the avg() function. And you don't define average outside the avg function Try the following:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
    var a = "${e://Fields/a}"
    var b = "${e://Fields/b}"
    var c = "${e://Fields/c}"

    a= parseFloat(a)
    b= parseFloat(b)
    c= parseFloat(c)
    var all_values= [a, b, c];
    function isnonzero(value) {
        return value != 0;
    }   
    var filter_it;
    filter_it = all_values.filter(isnonzero);
    function avg(filter_it){
        var sum = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < filter_it.length; i++) {
            sum += parseFloat(filter_it[i])
        }
        return sum / filter_it.length;
    }
    var average = avg(filter_it);
    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("total",average);

});
```

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. One question though- what is console.log? Going to try it in Qualtrics now

Comment: Ahh, that console.log can be removed from this code. I was using it for testing. console.log writes information to the browser javascript console.

Comment: cool- so it looks like that worked. so are you using console.log for checking your code? i haven't figured out an elegant way to check my javascript code in qualtrics yet.

Comment: Yes, console log is one of the many tools used for debugging in javascript. If you are struggling to debug, I would highly recommend doing some research on how debugging and the console work.